# Compilation error in strncpy in my code to find and print the longest word

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, strncpy

I have written a program to find the longest word and to print it.

### My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int MaxWord(char text[],char[]);

int main (void){
  char text[1000];
  char word[1000];
  int max;

  printf("geben Sie den Text bitte : ");
  gets(text);
  max=MaxWord(text,word);
  printf("ist mit %d Zeichen das laengste wort im Text\n\n\n",max);
  return 0;
}
int MaxWord(char text[], char word[])
{
  char i;
  int ctr=0;
  int max=0;
  int len;
  char begin=0;

  len=strlen(text);
  for(i=0;i<len+1;i++)
  {
    if(isalpha(text[i]))
    {
        if(ctr==0)
        {
            begin=i;
        }
        ctr++;
    }
    else 
    {

        if(ctr>max)
        {
            max=ctr;

        }

        ctr=0;
    }
 }
 strncpy(word,begin,max);
 printf("%s ",word);
 return max;
}
```

and the error is:

> error #2140: Type error in argument 2 to 'strncpy'; expected 'const char * restrict' but found 'char'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `gets`. Just starting out in C isn't a reasonable excuse for doing so.

Comment: @JohnColeman While true, `gets` is not related to the problem here.

Comment: read the error message? strncpy is expecting a pointer, and you passed in a char.

Comment: `strncpy()` expects its second argument to be a pointer to the source string.  You are passing a `char` instead.  Pass what it expects -- possibly something like `text + begin`.

Comment: @immibis I didn't say it was -- but I think that it is a civic duty to object to `gets` whenever it appears in code on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JohnColeman  i have to use gets for the strings and scanf can not solve the problem

Comment: @MahmoudAbosaleh `fgets` *can* solve the problem without risking buffer overflow.

Comment: Note also that type `char` likely is too narrow to index every element of a 1000-element array.  On most systems it is only 8 bits wide, and on many it is signed, so it may not be able to index more than 127 positions.  You probably want `begin` to be an `int` or `unsigned int` instead.

Comment: @MahmoudAbosaleh your wrong assumption is that `scanf` is the only alternate to `gets`

Comment: note that `strncpy` does not set the NULL character in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should not be using gets() function.  Use scanf instead. 
Also see 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

The function strncpy expects a const char* ( so that you are assured the function will not modify the source string ) and you are passing it a char. Hence the error. Please modify your function to pass in a char pointer.

You would need to recheck your logic and fix your strncpy call by passing in the right source string.

Comment: just like `gets`, but for a different reason, `strncpy` is never the right tool.

Comment: @bolov agreed. good link. the buffer overflow is definitely a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic in `MaxWord` is flawed: you always attempt to copy the last word encountered with the longest length.  The type `char` is inappropriate for `i` and `begin` as these are offsets in `text` potentially larger than `127`.

Furthermore, `strncpy` does not do what you think it does, it is an error prone function that can may not null terminate the destination buffer.  Do not use this function.

Do not use `gets` either because it cannot be used safely, invalid input will cause a buffer overflow.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int MaxWord(const char *text, char *word) {
    int i, ctr = 0, max = 0, len, begin = 0, best = 0;

    len = strlen(text);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)text[i])) {
            if (ctr == 0) {
                begin = i;
            }
            ctr++;
        } else {
            if (ctr > max) {
                best = begin;
                max = ctr;
            }
            ctr = 0;
        }
    }
    memcpy(word, test + best, max);
    word[max] = '\0';
    printf("%s ", word);
    return max;
}
```

It may seem surprising to cast `text[i]` as `(unsigned char)`, but `isalpha()` is defined as taking an `int` argument with the value of an `unsigned char` or the constant `EOF` (usually defined as `-1`).  If your compiler considers `char` to be a signed type, characters in `text` with the high bit set will be considered negative and will be sign extended when passed to `isalpha` potentially invoking incorrect or undefined behavior.

Another problem with your code is the determination of word boundaries: if you type in `laengste` correctly as `längste`, `isalpha()` may incorrectly consider the character or characters encoding the `ä` as a separator instead of a letter. Welcome to the intricate world of character encodings!

Comment: thank you it works  ;,,,by the way the logic of MaxWord I learned from the school ,,,

Comment: @MahmoudAbosaleh: If this answer was useful, click on the up arrow to vote it up and on the gray check mark to accept it.  Thank you.